# Template.registerHelper and UI.registerHelper

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

Quick question, I read that UI.registerHelper has been depreciated. But how come in my /lib/helper.js file using Template.registerHelper gets me a "Template is not defined" error. But when I switch it to  UI.registerHelper it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If lib is at the root of your project, it's probably because Template isn't defined on the server, and /lib would run on both client & server.  Try putting it in /client/lib/helper.js and see if that works.

Comment: Stephen, yup Template.registerHelper works in the client folder. Sorry to trouble you but could you share with me how to define the template in the server so that I can stop using UI.registerHelper in the root /lib and change to Template.registerHelper. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make sense to define it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't updated to the lasted version of Meteor. That might be it. I tried this and I got not no errors.